# How to show that supremum belongs to the set?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a real number $x \geq 0$ and a set $S=\{s \in \mathbb {Z}\mid s \leq x\}$. Let $a_0 = \sup S$. Prove that $a_0 \in S$.

This is the part of a theorem proof from Apostol’s analysis textbook. Although it is said to be very easy to show that $a_0 \in S$, I still struggle to do so. Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Show that $\mathbb{Z}\setminus S$ is non-empty. $S$ is also non-empty using the same argument with $-x$. The set $\mathbb{Z}\setminus S-a$ with $a\in S$ is a non-empty set of natural numbers. Therefore it has a minimum $b$. Define $a_0=b-1$. Show that $a_0\in S$ and it is a bound of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\geq 0$ be a real number. By construction, $S$ is bounded above by $x$. Let $a_0 = \sup S$.

Since $S$ is a nonempty collection of integers that is bounded above, it contains a maximum integer, call it $M$.

Then $M \leq a_0$ since $a_0$ is also an upper bound for $S$.

Further, for all $y \in S$, we have $y \leq M,$ so $M$ is an upper bound for $S$.

As $a_0$ is the smallest upper bound for $S$, we obtain $a_0 \leq M$.

Therefore, $a_0 = M$, so $a_0 \in S$.

Answer (score 0):

The supremum of a non-empty set is the  least upper bound of the set.

That is first of all every element of the set is less than or equal to the supremum which makes it an upper bound.

Secondly, if you pick a number which is less than the supremum, the set has an element which is larger than it.

In your case  the number $x$ satisfies both conditions  so  $$ \sup S=\{s\mid s \leq x\}=x$$

which obviously belongs to $S$.

Comment: Note the $s\in\mathbf{\mathbb{Z}}$ in the definition of $S$.